# Create custom big notification inflate

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to create a simple big notification, but I can't find what I am doing wrong. 
the notification even doesn't appear.

Edit: Ok, I found some problem but it is not fully working.
It was a problem with the View that I used to separate the lyaout(the simple gray line). I removed it and change the TextView to regular TextView and it is showing my layout now, but it's been cut, i cant see all the layout.
I use `.setCustomContentView(remoteViews)` to set the rmoteView. if I use `.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)` it show an empty notification, not with the layout.

So why `.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)` doesn't working?
And why I cant use my custom `TextView`?

this is my simple code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        RemoteViews remoteViews =  new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_add_driver_layout);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notifAddDriverIcon, R.drawable.my_trips_new);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(3, builder.build());
```

And this is my "notification_add_driver_layout" layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="140dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notifAddDriverIcon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_trips_new" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notifAddDriverTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notifAddDriverIcon"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notifAddDriverIcon"
    android:text="Need to update driver details"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notifAddDriverSubtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/notifAddDriverTitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/notifAddDriverTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:text="From one place to another\n in sunday 05.02.2017 at 09:00" />

<!--<View-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/separator"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="2dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignStart="@+id/notifAddDriverSubtitle"-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/notifAddDriverSubtitle"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginStart="12dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="19dp"-->
    <!--android:background="@color/chat_view_call_stroke" />-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/notifAddDriverButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/notifAddDriverSubtitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notifAddDriverText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="update details"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_reply" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is because of `com.smartbus.views.fonts.OpenSansTextViewBold`. Can you put that code? And put your logcat errors also.

Comment: I already check this. I opened new project and copy just the code I need for the notification, and change  `com.smartbus.views.fonts.OpenSansTextViewBold` to regular TextView

Comment: Can you put error appearing in your logcat?

Comment: It is no error in the logcat...

Comment: On which android version did u test this app??

Comment: android version  5.0.2

Comment: I edited my question. please check it. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required notification contents
A Notification object must contain the following:

1. A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
2. A title, set by setContentTitle()
3. Detail text, set by setContentText()

you don't have 2 and 3.

check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateANotification)

EDIT:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

And change your custom `TextView to regular`TextView`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135062/discussion-on-answer-by-mehran-zamani-create-custom-big-notification-inflate).

Answer (score 1):

On my device (Android 6.0.1), it is displayed but it is white (both background and text).

[image: white notif]

If you see it clearly, you can see the there is some text.

To make it visible I changed the background color.

```
android:background="@color/somecolor"
```

Dark blue in my case. Now it is visible.

[image: visible notif]